# Hosting Own Website and others

Tags: web-hosting

I might be on the wrong section to ask this but.

After signing up with Blue Host, for a personal website blog, i know i have the ability to add extra websites for free, however would it be possible for me to add someone else website that i don't own but gave me permission to add and i let them host their website on my plan.

can they still access their account without me giving them my blue host details.its kinda of a stupid question, once i think about it.

any help will do.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in one way..

STEP-1
You have to create different FTP accounts for all users and provide a seperate folder to all users they can access that folder only via FTP details.

They can add/update/delete files that they owns.

STEP-2

Tell you user to forward his/her `domain` to `yousite.com/folder-assign` to FTP

FINISHED

Now what happen when someone open your users site.

lets says your domain is `YOURDOMAIN.COM` and your user domain is `MYUSERDOMAIN.COM`, now your user have forwarded his/her domain to your domain `YOURDOMAIN.COM/FOLDER_ASSGIN` to FTP

-In URL user see their own domain name `MYUSERDOMAIN.COM` actually it opens your site's folder that is assign to your user